# Remove all duplicate word from string using shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, xargs, duplicate

I have a string like

```
"aaa,aaa,aaa,bbb,bbb,ccc,bbb,ccc"
```

I want to remove duplicate word from string then output will be like

```
"aaa,bbb,ccc"
```

I tried This code [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802734/sorting-and-removing-duplicate-words-in-a-line)

```
$ echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs
```

It is working fine with same value,but when I give my variable value then it is showing all duplicate word also.

How can I  remove duplicate value.

**UPDATE**

My question is adding all corresponding value into a single string  if user is same .I have data like this ->

```
   user name    | colour
    AAA         | red
    AAA         | black
    BBB         | red
    BBB         | blue
    AAA         | blue
    AAA         | red
    CCC         | red
    CCC         | red
    AAA         | green
    AAA         | red
    AAA         | black
    BBB         | red
    BBB         | blue
    AAA         | blue
    AAA         | red
    CCC         | red
    CCC         | red
    AAA         | green
```

In coding  I fetch all distinct user then I concatenate color string successfully .For that I am using code  -

```
while read the records 

    if [ "$c" == "" ]; then  #$c I defined global
        c="$colour1"
    else
        c="$c,$colour1" 
    fi
```

When I print this $c variable i get the output (For User AAA)

```
"red,black,blue,red,green,red,black,blue,red,green,"
```

I want to remove duplicate color .Then desired output should be  like

```
"red,black,blue,green"
```

For this desired output i used above code

```
 echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs
```

but it is displaying the output with duplicate values .Like

"red,black,blue,red,green,red,black,blue,red,green,"
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what is wrong with what you are using. I don't understand what you mean by "when I give my variable value". What value do you give? Where does it fail?

Comment: `echo 'aaa aaa aaa bbb bbb ccc bbb ccc' | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs` gives `aaa bbb ccc`.. so you need to show exact code you tired and output you got.. with the string in variable: `s='aaa aaa aaa bbb bbb ccc bbb ccc'; echo "$s" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs`

Comment: string value comes dynamically. It is printing same  value (contain duplicate value).

Comment: yeah, show the code that failed, otherwise how would we know what could've gone wrong?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes order matter.I updated my question so you can easily understand.

Comment: @Sundeep i updated my answer  please see.

Comment: @Urvashi your string uses `,` as delimiter while the code you found worked on space as delimiter... why do you expect it to work on your string? all answers attempted will now be invalidated because of that

Comment: when i tried that code that time i remove(,) and place space.But after that also i did not get it work.

Comment: again we cannot debug code which you don't show, also your expected output `"red,black,blue,red,green,"` has `red` repeated... and `,` at end of string is required?

Comment: @Sundeep  red,black,blue,green" this is desired ,It was typing mistake.I corrected.

Comment: try a simple `awk` + `paste` command instead of shell scripting, `awk '$1=="AAA" {if(!seen[$3]++) print $3}' input.txt | paste -sd,` where you need to replace `input.txt` with name of your file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55947/discussion-between-urvashi-and-sundeep).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One more awk, just for fun:

```
$ a="aaa bbb aaa bbb ccc aaa ddd bbb ccc"
$ echo "$a" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}'
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

By the way, even your solution works fine with variables:

```
$ b="zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant" 
$ echo "$b" | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs
ant spider zebra
```

Comment: Neat approach. The only adjustment I had to make was to use `%s` instead of `%s%s`. The reason being is that I was doing a for loop through the results and two white spaces caused some challenges with regex matches.

Comment: what if there are other word separators, such as dots, involved?

Answer (score 13):

With `tr`, `sort` and `uniq`

```
echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u
```

or

```
echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | xargs
```

to get one line

Comment: You need to add  `| xargs` to join the output to one line again

Comment: Or use `sort -u`. Or even a `awk '!u[$0]++`.

Comment: @Benoît Wow, I did not know about `sort -u`. I've been using `sort | uniq` all this time. The wasted keystrokes...

Answer (score 9):

```
$ echo "zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant"  | awk -v RS="[ \n]+" '!n[$0]++' 
zebra
ant
spider
```

Comment: Very clever!!!!

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, thank you [or to tell the truth, very lazy :-) ]

Answer (score 3):

With gnu `sed`:

```
sed ':s;s/\(\<\S*\>\)\(.*\)\<\1\>/\1\2/g;ts'
```

You may add `;s/  */ /g` to remove dublicate spaces.

Functions like this: If a word is a second time in this line, remove it and start over until no dublication is found anymore.

Comment: What are `\<` and `\>`?

Comment: @someonewithpc They match no character, but the beginning and end of a word to prevent substrings from being matched.

Comment: Nice, but is that portable? Also, aren't words separated by whitespace? Seems redundant to match not whitespace followed by the end of a word.

Comment: @someonewithpc No, it's not standard, that's why I wrote _gnu sed_. The nice part is that you don't have to handle first and last string separately

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '$,=$";print grep { ! $h{$_}++ } @F'
```

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory awk solution:

```
$ echo "ant zebra ant spider spider ant zebra ant" | 
   awk -vRS=" " -vORS=" " '!a[$1] {a[$1]++} END{ for (x in a) print x;  } ' ; echo
zebra ant spider
```

(The final `echo` is there for the newline)

Comment: Plus one for the awk ! I was builting also an awk solution just for fun. There is a slight possibility words to be printed in random order at END section due to the random way that awk itterates in array keys.

Comment: Yes, they will be printed in an essentially random order. The `sort` solution doesn't keep the original order either, though.

Comment: Yes, good point! Even sort prints in different order than input.

Comment: @ilkkachu Actually we don't need to wait for the input to end. We can make decision to print or not to print with a slight modification to your code: `awk -vRS=" " -vORS=" " '!a[$1]++ {print $1}' ; echo` This preserves the order.

Answer (score 1):

### Python

#### Option 1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# get_unique_words.py

import sys

l = []
for w in sys.argv[1].split(','):
  if w not in l:
    l += [ w ]
print ','.join(l)
```

Make executable, then call from Bash:

```
$ ./get_unique_words.py "aaa,aaa,aaa,bbb,bbb,ccc,bbb,ccc"
aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Or you could implement it as a Bash function, but the syntax is messy.

```
get_unique_words(){
  python -c "
l = []
for w in '$1'.split(','):
  if w not in l:
    l += [ w ]
print ','.join(l)"
}
```

#### Option 2

This option can become a one-liner if needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# get_unique_words.py

import sys

s_in = sys.argv[1]
l_in = s_in.split(',') # Turn string into a list.
set_out = set(l_in) # Turning a list into a set removes duplicates items.
s_out = ','.join(set_out) 
print s_out
```

In Bash:

```
get_unique_words(){
  python -c "print ','.join(set('$1'.split(',')))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat filename | awk '{ delete a; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]++; n=asorti(a, b); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf b[i]" "; print "" }' > newfile
```

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: Your code lack explanation. With no explanation, it's difficult to follow what's happening. You also seem to make assumptions about the data that seems wrong (whitespace-delimited fields) and about the particular `awk` implementation being used (`asorti()` is not a standard `awk` function).

Answer (score 0):

Using the original tabular data in the file called `file`:

```
sed '1d' file | sort -u |
awk '{ color[$1] = ( color[$1] == "" ? $3 : color[$1] "," $3 ) }
     END { for (user in color) print user, color[user] }'
```

This generates

```
CCC red
BBB blue,red
AAA black,blue,green,red
```

The three steps of the pipeline:

1. The `sed` command removes the first line which is a header that we don't want to read.
2. The `sort` command gives us unique lines.  The sample data after the `sort` looks like

   ```
   AAA         | black
   AAA         | blue
   AAA         | green
   AAA         | red
   BBB         | blue
   BBB         | red
   CCC         | red
   ```
3. The `awk` command takes this data and produces a comma-delimited string for each user in the array `color` (where the username is the key into the array). At the end (in the `END` block), all collected data is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a weird issue where each file title was doubled, and sought a way to fix that:

```bsh
❯ ls
01 Miracle Miracle.mp3
02 Spirit of Life Spirit of Life.mp3
03 Let It Be (feat. Veela).mp3
04 Embrace Embrace.mp3
05 Don't Let Me Down (feat. Cat Martin) Don't Let Me Down (feat. Cat Martin).mp3
06 My Love My Love.mp3
07 The Drift The Drift.mp3
08 Lucid Truth Lucid Truth.mp3
09 Love At Heart Love At Heart.mp3
10 Sarajevo (Blackmill Remix) Sarajevo (Blackmill Remix).mp3
11 Fortune Soul Fortune Soul.mp3
```

I adapted the [sed script of Philippos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353326/272449):

```bsh
❯ ls | sed ':s;s/ \([^ ]\+\) \(.*\)\1/ \1 \2/g;ts'
01 Miracle .mp3
02 Spirit of Life   .mp3
03 Let It Be (feat. Veela).mp3
04 Embrace .mp3
05 Don't Let Me Down (feat. Cat Martin)       .mp3
06 My Love  .mp3
07 The Drift  .mp3
08 Lucid Truth  .mp3
09 Love At Heart   .mp3
10 Sarajevo (Blackmill Remix)   .mp3
11 Fortune Soul  .mp3
```

And used it to fix the filenames:

```bsh
❯ find -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -v "{}" "$(echo "{}" | sed ":s;s/ \([^ ]\+\) \(.*\)\1/ \1 \2/g;ts" | sed "s/ \+\././")"' \;
mv: './03 Let It Be (feat. Veela).mp3' and './03 Let It Be (feat. Veela).mp3' are the same file
renamed './06 My Love My Love.mp3' -> './06 My Love.mp3'
renamed './10 Sarajevo (Blackmill Remix) Sarajevo (Blackmill Remix).mp3' -> './10 Sarajevo (Blackmill Remix).mp3'
renamed './07 The Drift The Drift.mp3' -> './07 The Drift.mp3'
renamed './04 Embrace Embrace.mp3' -> './04 Embrace.mp3'
renamed './05 Don'\''t Let Me Down (feat. Cat Martin) Don'\''t Let Me Down (feat. Cat Martin).mp3' -> './05 Don'\''t Let Me Down (feat. Cat Martin).mp3'
renamed './02 Spirit of Life Spirit of Life.mp3' -> './02 Spirit of Life.mp3'
renamed './09 Love At Heart Love At Heart.mp3' -> './09 Love At Heart.mp3'
renamed './01 Miracle Miracle.mp3' -> './01 Miracle.mp3'
renamed './11 Fortune Soul Fortune Soul.mp3' -> './11 Fortune Soul.mp3'
renamed './08 Lucid Truth Lucid Truth.mp3' -> './08 Lucid Truth.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -ne 'state %h; next if $++ == 0; .split(/ "|" | \s+ /, :skip-empty) andthen %h.=append($_.[0] => $_.[1]); END say(.key => .value.unique) for %h.sort;'
```

Sample Input:

```
   user name    | colour
    AAA         | red
    AAA         | black
    BBB         | red
    BBB         | blue
    AAA         | blue
    AAA         | red
    CCC         | red
    CCC         | red
    AAA         | green
    AAA         | red
    AAA         | black
    BBB         | red
    BBB         | blue
    AAA         | blue
    AAA         | red
    CCC         | red
    CCC         | red
    AAA         | green
```

Sample Output:

```
AAA => (red black blue green)
BBB => (red blue)
CCC => (red)
```

Briefly, input is read using Raku's `-ne` "linewise, non-autoprinting" commandline flags. A hash `%h` is `state`d (once). The statement `next if $++ == 0;` is used to skip the header line. Each line is `split` on either `|` pipe or `\s+` whitespace, empty elements are skipped. Resultant username and colour elements are `append`ed to the `%h` hash in a username `=>` colour (key `=>` value) relationship. Because keys must be unique in the `%h` hash, `.values` accrue to the appropriate `.key`.

At the `END` (after all lines are read), the code `say`s keys and their `unique` values. To get output where key/value columns are separated by `\t` tabs, change `say` into `put`.

Answer (score -1):

```
a="aaa aaa aaa bbb bbb ccc bbb ccc"
for item in $a
do
   echo $item
done | sort -u | (while read i; do ans="$ans $i"; done ; echo $ans)
```

Explanation:

1. We are reading line in the "for" loop and convert each word in the original line into list's item. So, we are receiving a list of original  words.
2. Then we sort the list obtained in the first step and remove all duplicates using "sort -u".
3. At the last step we are reading our deduplicated list and transform it into a single string.

Comment: Please add an explanation on how your code works and why you did this and that.